# How to update Windows 10 from an ISO or another PC

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, updates

I currently live in a country where internet is too expensive to download Windows updates. I have completely turned off the Windows update service. I have missed the Anniversary Update and now the Creators update. I have a desktop and a laptop computer. I would like to update them both without having to pay a million dollars in bandwidth and redundantly downloading it twice. In fact I would like to just have a friend download the update and mail it to me. But is this possible?

I know you can download or create an ISO of the Creators update, but then the instructions I read online make it sound like you can only use it to do a fresh install of Windows 10. Is there no way to just update an existing Win 10 installation? Could I run the install program from the ISO and just tell it to "repair" Windows, instead of a clean install? Would that achieve an update and leave my programs and files undisturbed?

I have also heard rumours that it is possible to get Windows Update to get files from other computers on the local network, but then it sounds like it would just get some parts from the network and still want to download other parts from MS, depending on what mood it is in? Or is there a way to force it to only update from the local network? If so, then maybe I could just find someone who has an up-to-date Windows 10 and leech off of them. But what if they have Windows 10 Pro, while I only have Home?

I wish tech companies didn't just assume everyone lives in the 1st world with unlimited internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update from the ISO - just run the setup application off it, and it'll handle the rest. In this case, the [media creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10) is your best choice, and it'll let you pick your version and architectures iirc

I also believe you can update directly to the most recent version rather than having to upgrade between major releases

Comment: I hope you're right. Ill give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can download Microsoft update package with KB number from Microsoft update catalog and install them just like a standalone installer. Check your system compatibility with that update.
Website:: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx

Ok let's take an example. Like if you want to download the latest update of Windows 10, e.g. [May 9, 2017—KB4016871 (OS Build 15063.296 and 15063.297)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4016871/windows-10-update-kb4016871).

Then go to [Microsoft update catalog](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4016871) search for "kb4016871" in right upper corner. And you get this search result::
http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4016871

Then chose what OS type do you have --64bit or 32bit. If you have 64bit OS, then download the update package which name end with x64. After downloading the update package double click on it to install.
There may be two or more package for one update.

In this process you don't need the full iso file. Just get the update package only. See this site for more details::

[How to download updates that include drivers and hotfixes from the Windows Update Catalog](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/323166/how-to-download-updates-that-include-drivers-and-hotfixes-from-the-windows-update-catalog)

Comment: I don't know how to use that page. I don't know what to search for. I searched for "Creators" and it returned all sorts of junk. Mostly hardware updates. I guess if I know what to look for it could be handy.

Comment: The above process is to download only some selective update not the whole window 10 system.

Answer (score 1):

Another choice, if you already downloaded the update but somehow it failed to install, you can reinstall it without redownloading using a hidden folder under your main drive (C: usually) it's called $WINDOWS~BT, I believe you can create an ISO installation from it.

Comment: Interesting. How does that folder work? Does it just store whatever the last Windows updates were?

Comment: If it's a major update, that's where it will be stored, other updates are usually under a Software Distribution folder.